# AuthUserSession is null inside ServiceStack service after successful auth

Tags: servicestack

I have a self hosted service stack app in which I'm using Facebook Oath and Redis - the Facebook and redis side of things seem to be working ie. when I visit

```
abc.com/auth/facebook
```

The custom user session gets populated in OnAuthenticated method. The Redis cache has the data persisted correctly..so far so good

The problem Im having is understanding how to retrieve this CustomUserSession in a subsequent request. To begin with the oauth redirect page "/About-Us" is where I want to retrieve the session value however it is always null

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{      
    [DataMember]
    public string CustomId { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        // receiving session id here and can retrieve from redis cache
    }
    public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
    {
        // when using the [Authenticate] attribute - this Id is always
        // a fresh value and so doesn't exist in cache and cannot be auth'd
        string sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(this.Id);

        cacheClient = ServiceStackHost.Instance.TryResolve<ICacheClient>();
        CustomUserSession session = cacheClient.Get<CustomUserSession>(sessionKey);

        if (session == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return session.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}


[DefaultView("AboutUs")]
public class AboutUsService : AppServiceBase
{
    public object Get(AboutUsRequest request)
    {
        var sess = base.UserSession;
        return new AboutUsResponse
        {
            //custom Id is always null?? 
            Name = sess.CustomId
        };
    }
}
public abstract class AppServiceBase : Service
{
    protected CustomUserSession UserSession
    {
        get
        {
            return base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        }
    }
}
```

How I register the cache & session etc.

```
        AppConfig = new AppConfig(appSettings);
        container.Register(AppConfig);
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("10.1.1.10:6379"));
        container.Register(c =>
              c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
        ConfigureAuth(container, appSettings);
```

the contents of ConfigureAuth()

```
        var authFeature = new AuthFeature(
            () => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings), // override of BasicAuthProvider
            }
            ) {HtmlRedirect = null, IncludeAssignRoleServices = false};

        Plugins.Add(authFeature);
```

I feel I'm missing something obvious here.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To register to use a `CustomUserSession` for your typed Sessions, it needs to be specified when you register the AuthFeature, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), ...));
```

Comment: @MikeW Is it just `CustomId` that's null? If so where are you populating it and is the session being saved after?

Comment: the session object is new() , all the values for the session are there when OnAuthenticate is called like CustomId and Facebook Email etc .. In Redis Monitor I can see the session data being SET with the key. Then the redirect to the razor page where I try and retrieve the values - I can link you the project code if it helps

Comment: @MikeW does the `SET` in Redis Monitor contain the `CustomId`? Can you also see the `GET` redis request to access the custom session, is it using the same session key?

Comment: The customId is SET I can see in redis monitor, but when I run "get keys" I get always get {nil} - not sure why its either not persisting or being deleted immediately, the subsequent request uses a different sessionId and creates a new session - so I seem to get getting 2 GETs and 2 SETs per request. I'll try a few tests with a different server and report back.

Comment: The redis server seems to be functioning fine - keys * (not get keys...my mistake) pulls out all the facebook sessions. It creates a new session with one key and then the facebook data with another key, subsequent requests are all with unique keys - not sure why though...

Comment: @MikeW you'd want to look at the HTTP Request/Response headers. Once the Session Cookies are set each subsequent request should send the same cookies and access the same session, if that's not the case either something is clearing the Session Cookies, replacing them with new ones or Cookies is disabled.